# Could not import golang dependencies

Tags: go

I am just starting with go and while trying to create an autoscaler implementation for the kubernetes external grpc autoscaler plugin. For that I am trying to use [the example code](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/externalgrpc/examples/external-grpc-cloud-provider-service) provided by the kubernetes devs.

Unfortunately I am failing at the very beginning at importing the required packages. Both my IDE and the compoler are saying, that I am missing some dependencies which I can't install even after a successful `go get`.

One of the error messages is:
`could not import k8s.io/autoscaler/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/builder (no required module provides package "k8s.io/autoscaler/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/builder")`

Thats the output of the go get command:

```
$ go get k8s.io/autoscaler/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/builder
go: downloading k8s.io/autoscaler v0.0.0-20230630125842-e6397c65a2c8
go: downloading k8s.io/autoscaler/cluster-autoscaler v0.0.0-20230630125842-e6397c65a2c8
go: downloading k8s.io/legacy-cloud-providers v0.0.0
go: downloading k8s.io/kube-scheduler v0.0.0
go: downloading k8s.io/kubectl v0.0.0
go: downloading k8s.io/dynamic-resource-allocation v0.0.0
go: reading k8s.io/api/go.mod at revision v0.0.0: unknown revision v0.0.0
```

Hopefully someone of you can give me the correct hint to start over.
Thank you very much!

BR,
Alex

Comment: Have you run `go mod tidy`?

Comment: Yeah, already tried that but this just messes up my go.mod and I am getting much more errors as before as the compiler is missing some more packages as before.

Comment: Did you tried to run `go mod init` before everything? and check that has a file named `go.mod` in your project folder

Comment: Yeah of course. This was the first thing I did.

Comment: That example is already contained within a module, and will build without any additional input, and does not need its own `go.mod`. If you want to copy that code outside of the module, their `go.mod` uses a lot of `replace` directives which you will need to copy in order to get the project to build.

Comment: Building on the comment by @JimB, have you tried starting with the *go.mod* and *go.sum* found at the root of that project: https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Now some more things make sense to me. I think you are absolutely correct with the whole repo being one go module. So I think it does not make sense to use their example code for an own implementation of the grpc server as it is completely packed into the whole thing?